# ASP.NET MasterPageFile causing error

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm trying to use a master page in my website.  I created a page and then created the master.  I then added the tag MasterPageFile="~/master".  I'm guessing that I need to do something to my main page, because I've now started getting the error:

```
The page contains markup that is not valid when attached to a master page
```

My main page is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" MasterPageFile="~/my.master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>

     </div>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried deleting the  tag thinking that this might be the issue.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your `body` to `content` sections. The master page works with `contentplaceholders`: your content pages need to provide the content for these placeholders. [See the msdn page on this topic.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx)

Quoted from that link above, your master page could contain the following:

```
<td><asp:contentplaceholder id="Main" runat="server" /></td>
```

Which the content page would fill by supplying the following

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>
```

Note that I included the main declaration at the top of the content page.

Answer (score 1):

the pages inhering master page should have a `<asp:Content` as their root. this means no html tag no doctype etc.